# Overfitting terminology in Machine Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In the book [Introduction to Machine Learning with Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449369413) on page 50 the author is performing a Linear Regression on a dataset and gets:

```
training set score: 0.67
test set score: 0.66
```

They then state that they are “likely underfitting, not overfitting.”

However, when using TensorFlow’s [Basic Classification Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification) they are using the MNIST Fashion dataset with a neural network and get:

```
training set score: 0.892
test set score: 0.876
```

and then they state the following

“It turns out, the accuracy on the test dataset is a little less than the accuracy on the training dataset. This gap between training accuracy and test accuracy is an example of overfitting. Overfitting is when a machine learning model performs worse on new data than on their training data.”

I believe that the quote taken from the TensorFlow site is the correct one, or are they both correct and I don’t fully understand overfitting.

Comment: Since this question is not about programming per se, I'd rather ask it at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there a way to move it over?

Comment: or to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Over- and under-fitting

The most overfit you can do is have an accuracy of `100%` on your training set.
This means that your model learned to predict exactly inputs that it has seen before.
If you are ever in this situation, your test set will probably perform very poorly.

You can detect overfitting by:

- High accuracy on the training set
- a large gap between training and test set

You can detect underfitting by:

- A low accuracy on the training set (irrespective of performance on test set)

#### Examples:

1)

```
training set score: 0.67
test set score: 0.66
```

This example has a low score on training set. So underfitting seems like a fair assumption.

2)

```
training set score: 0.892
test set score: 0.876
```

This one is up to interpretation. The score on the training set is quite high and there is a gap in respect to the test set.

If the examples in both sets are very similar, then I would say that there is some overfitting. However, if the two sets are quite different (for example from different sources), then the results could be deemed acceptable.

Comment: "Low" and "high" very much depend on the problem at hand. Your example 1) is misleading as 0.67 can very indeI would first look at the definition on the Wiki, and in particular this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting#Machine_learning

Comment: The example is not mine, is from OP. I agree low and high is misleading, but up to interpretation. That is why I say *fair* assumption, still need to check to see if indeed is low. All this under-overfitting is for a first estimate and see what to try next.

Comment: Indeed, the comment about example was wrong I intended to remove it, but did not clean it up completely :). I think, the problem here is that there is no "first estimate". Because there is no clear guidance for what is "low" and what is "high".

Answer (score 1):

Underfitting occurs when both the training and testing accuracies are low. This signifies a systematic problem with your model, i.e the data would fit better with a polynomial model but you're using a linear model. So a ~66% accuracy for both training and testing is considered underfitting because they are both very low. In general, high error on both sets indicates underfitting.

Overfitting occurs when you have relatively high accuracy on training, but lower on testing. This signifies that your model has fit too much towards your training data, and does not generalize well to other data. In general, low error on training and higher error on testing indicates overfitting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would you say that the quote taken from the book is incorrect or no?

Comment: @G.LC I don't think it's incorrect to say it's underfitting. The fact that both sets have such poor scores overshadows the fact that they are 1% apart. There is probably a model that fits the data better

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is **extremely rare** to build a model, that would show the same performance on the training and validation (or test, or holdout, whatever you wish to call it) sets. Thus, the gap between training and validation set will be there (almost) always. You will see the definition of overfitting based on the gap often, but in practice it is not applicable as it is not quantitative. The more general concept here is the *"bias-variance trade-off"*, that you might want to google about. The relevant question is how large is the gap, how good is performance and how performance on the validation set behaves with changed complexity of the model.

I find this figure from Wikipedia very instructive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting#/media/File:Overfitting_svg.svg. The x axis is the number of training iterations (epochs) in the case of NN or GBM's, but you can also think of it as a model complexity parameter, e.g. the number of powers included in a polynomial model. As you can see, there is always a gap between performance on the training and validation samples. But the key to choose the model that does not overfit is to choose the **optimal trade-off** between performance on the training sample (= bias) and performance on the validation sample (the difference between performance on training and validation samples = variance).